# generate_series() function missing PostgreSQL

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, generate-series

I'm having some trouble with my application. It works in my development environment but not on my customers server..

The generate_series with timestamps does not work. The same function but with integers work.

**Error message:**

```
 [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] with root cause
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function generate_series(unknown, unknown, interval) does not exist
      Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I can't locate the function in PostgreSQL. Where can I get a copy of these methods so I can install them if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention your PostgreSQL version, but

```
generate_series(timestamp, timestamp, interval)
```

was not available before 8.4

So maybe you are using an outdated version?

Comment: oh, god.. I have to check that

Comment: Yes! Old version. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @heldt In pre 8.4 versions it is possible to replicate the new functionality with the old function signature. Just post the question about how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You must pass `timestamp` values as the first two function parameters. Or cast them:

```
generate_series('2011-12-31'::timestamp, '2012-12-31'::timestamp, '1 day')
```